# Describe the homomorphism induced on the fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider the unit circle $S^1$ and consider the continuous application f: $S^1 \to S^1$, f(z)=$\bar{z}^mz^n$, where $\bar{z}$ indicates the conjugate of z and $n,m \in \mathbf{Z}$. 
The exercise asks me to describe the homomorphism induced on the fundamental group 
$f_\ast: \pi_1(S^1,1) \to \pi_1(S^1,1) $. My question is what means describe the homomorphism induced on the fundamental group? Does anyone know how I should proceed?

Answer (score 1):

The elements of $\pi_1(S^1, 1)$ are closed paths starting (and ending) at $1$.  Let $p \in \pi_1(S^1, 1)$, so that $p: [0,1] \rightarrow S^1$ with $p(0) = p(1) = 1$.

You have several maps $f$, depending on the choices of $m$ and $n$.  As written, $f$ is a map from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$, but we restrict it to $|z| = 1$ so that the restriction is a map from the complex unit circle to itself.

To allow $f$ to compose with $p$, we must identify the $S^1$ codomain of $p$ with the unit complex circle.  $S^1 \cong \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| = 1\}$  Having done so, we are ready to ask, what is $f \circ p$?

Note that $f \circ p : [0,1] \rightarrow S^1$, so the $f$-images of each loop in $\pi_1(S^1,1)$ are loops in $S^1$.  Since $f \circ p(0) = f(1) = 1$ and $f \circ p(1) = f(1) = 1$ for any $m,n$, the $f$-images of each loop in $\pi_1(S^1,1)$ are loops in $\pi_1(S^1,1)$.  So from $f$, a map of points to points, we get another map, $f_*:\pi_1(S^1,1) \rightarrow \pi_1(S^1,1)$, a group homomorphism.  This map is the homomorphism induced on the fundamental group.

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
[0,1] @>{p}>> S^1 @. @. \pi_1(S^1,1)\\
@. @V{f}VV @. @V{f_*}VV \\
@.  S^1 @. @. \pi_1(S^1,1);
\end{CD}$$

Each equivalence class of loops in $\pi_1(S^1,1)$ has a representative, $p_k: x \mapsto \mathrm{e}^{2\pi \mathrm{i} k x}$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Each of these is a suitable $p$ in the discussion above.  The set of these maps $\{p_k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a complete set of representatives of the equivalence classes in $\pi_1(S^1,1)$.  Now, for each choice of $(m,n)$ study the set $\{f \circ p_k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

The behaviour is different for different choices of $m$ and $n$.  For $m = 0$, $n = 1$, this $f$ is the identity, so $f_*(p_k) = p_k$ and the induced map is an isomorphism.  For $m = n = 0$, $f$ is the constant map $z \mapsto 1$, so this $f$ induces the trivial homomorphism.  Other choices of $m$ and $n$ will show maps to various subgroups of $\pi(S^1,1)$.  It is possible to write down (in a short way) which subgroup is the image of the induced homomorphism as a function of $m$ and $n$ and you are asked to find this short specification.  Note that $\pi_1(S^1,1) = \langle p_1 \mid \rangle$ (that is, is infinite cyclic with generator $p_1$), so as soon as you can specify $f_*(p_1)$ as a function of $m$ and $n$, you have completely specified the homomorphism $f_*$.

Comment: how have I to specify $f_\ast(p_1)$ as a function of m and n?

Comment: $f_\ast(p_1)$ is the same at what in this case?

Comment: @Giusy : Each $(m,n)$ gives a different $f$ and hence a different $f_*$.  It might be better to write $f(m,n): S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ and $(f(m,n))_*: \pi_1(S^1,1) \rightarrow \pi_1(S^1,1)$ to more clearly show that each $f$ depends on $m$ and $n$.  Also, you have $p_k:[0,1] \rightarrow S^1 \subset \mathbb{C}$ and $f(m,n):\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ as *explicit maps*, so you should have no trouble computing $f(m,n) \circ p_k$ and finding its winding number (around $0+0\mathrm{i}$).

Comment: can you say me how I have to do for example for m=1 and n=1?

Comment: $f(1,1)(z) = (\overline{z})^1 z^1 = |z|^2$, so $f(m,n) \circ p_k(x) = |\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i}k x}|^2 = 1$.  Since $p_0(x) = 1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, this says $f(1,1)(p_k) = p_0$, the representative of the identity in $\pi_1(S^1,1)$, so $(f(m,n))_*(g) = 1$ for all $g \in \pi_1(S^1,1)$.

Comment: if n=0 and m=1 $f$ is identity as the case m=0 and n=1?

Comment: @Giusy : Not quite.  $f(1,0)(p_k) = p_{-k}$ and $f(0,1)(p_k) = p_k$.  Recall that $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$ winds in the positive direction and $\overline{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}} = \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\theta}$ winds in the negative direction.

Comment: why so f(m,n)∘p_k(x)=|e^2πikx|^2=1?

Comment: @Giusy : Points on the unit circle all have magnitude $1$.  And the equality you write depends on $m$ and $n$.  It is not true for all choices of $m$ and $n$.  That comment was a response to your specification $m = n = 1$.

Comment: And for example |e^2πikx|^3 at what is equal?

Comment: @Giusy : $|\mathrm{e}^{2 \pi \mathrm{i} k x}|^3 = 1^3 = 1$.  But I think you are lost in the weeds.  This used the fact that $\overline{z} z = |z|^2$.  What are you going to do when $m \neq n$?

Comment: I really didn't understand what to do when m is different to n

Comment: @Giusy : You have *explicit* maps for $f(m,n)$ and $p_k$.  What is the general expression for $f(m,n) \circ p_k$ ?

Comment: |e^2i| right??

Comment: @Giusy  : No.  That's $|p_k(x)|$.  You gave $f(m,n)$ in your problem statement.  It is not the function that returns the magnitude of its argument.

Comment: if m=2 and n=3 how I have to proceed? Sorry, but It is the first time that I do this exercise.

Comment: Let's take small steps.  What is $f(m,n)(z)$, where we *do not* assign particular values to $m$ and $n$?

Comment: That’s f(z)=$\bar{z}^^$?

Comment: Yes.  What's $p_k(x)$?  Then, what's $f(m,n) \circ p_k(x)$?

Comment: $p_k$ is :[0,1]→1 right? And then I don’t know how to write explicitly f(m,n) o $p_k(x)$

Comment: $p_k(x) = \mathrm{e}^{2 \pi \mathrm{i} k x}$.  Are you unable to put this into your equation for $f(m,n)$?

Comment: In f(z)=$\bar{z}^mz^n$ I replace $e^{2ikx\pi}$ in z, right?

Comment: @Giusy : Yes.  Getting ... ?

Comment: (e^-2)^m(e^2)^n?

Comment: Can you simplify that to $\mathrm{e}^{2\pi \mathrm{i} \text{(some expression in $m$, $n$, and $k$)}}$ to discover $f(m,n) \circ p_k(x) = p_j$ for $j$ a function of $k$, $m$, and $n$.

Comment: Okay now if m=3 and n=2 (e^-2)^3(e^2)^2 at what is equal?

Comment: @Giusy : This is "just algebra".  $\mathrm{e}^{2 \pi \mathrm{i} (-3k + 2k) x} = \mathrm{e}^{-2 \pi \mathrm{i} k x} = p_{-k}(x)$.

Comment: Oooh yes, now I understood thank you very much

Comment: So that I can save a lot of time the next time I'm asked this sort of question: What was the obstruction to understanding?

Comment: Maybe the analytic form of $p_k$

Comment: Eric Towers could you help me in my other question on how to determine the homomorfism induced by $f:D^2 \to D^2$??

Comment: @Giusy : This seems pretty straightforward because $\pi_1(D^2)$ has very, very few elements.

Comment: And could you help me to risolve it?

Comment: @Giusy : Not until you show me you know how many elements $\pi_1(D^2)$ has.

Comment: I know that fundamental group of D^2 is trivial. For example its generator could be $\alpha$ with relation $\alpha=1$. Right?

Comment: @Giusy : So what are *all* possible homomorphisms $\pi_1(D^2) \rightarrow \pi_1(D^2)$?  You have one element to send and only one place for it to go...

Comment: The identity. Right??

Comment: @Giusy : Yes.  So how many ways to make a map from a one element set to a one element set are there?

Comment: One, right? And then What should I do?